# Avoid header being pushed by KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I have a container component in a stack navigator with the header on top, a scrollview containing messages and a input element

When I focus the input the whole window gets pushed up, hiding also the header

How can I avoid this behaviour?

This is the component I'm using:

```
class Chat extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: (
        <Header
          user={navigation.getParam('chat').partecipants[0]}
          headerClick={() => navigation.getParam('openProfile')()}
        />
      )
    }
  }

.....

  render() {
    ...
    return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{flex: 1}}
      behavior={'padding'}
      >
      <ScrollView>
        {messages}
      </ScrollView>
      <Input sendMessage={(m) => this.props.sendMessage(chat, m)}/>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an existing bug with KeyboardAvoidingView when StatusBar is set to hidden
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12980

Removing the hidden flag it behaves normally

Answer (score 0):

In androidmanifest.xml
Change
--- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" --- 
to
--- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ---

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. It seems related with the statusbar bug

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyboardAwareScrollView it allows to specify extraHeight prop above the keyboard